Mac OS AnyDesk gets stuck both in launch and installation
I used AnyDesk 7.2.1 in Mac OS 10.13 for quite some time and it worked perfectly, when suddenly I tried to launch it and it did nothing. The day that this happened I had a weak internet connection when I started the computer (AnyDesk started automatically on computer start up). I restarted the system, having a stable internet connection and the problem remained.
I then followed AnyDesk website instructions for uninstalling the application, so that to install the latest version 8.1.2 (it is compatible with my OS). I tried both full and portable installations but they both failed. In the case of full installation, the installer gets stuck when I press "Agree and Install", while in the case of portable installation it launches and no window opens and it does nothing.
I searched for possible solutions, and I tried also to give it Security Permissions, but again nothing changed.
I also tried to install a previous version 7.0.2 (similar to that I had) but again the  problem remains.
I also searched for cached files and folders that AnyDesk creates in the system and I found this. I also cleared all these files mentioned in the article and again nothing changed.
When the installer starts or the application tries to launch both get stuck. The only possible reason I can think of, is that there must be some saved configuration or cached files that prevent it from launching but I cannot find any.
Any ideas?

Welcome to Ask Different.  Do you need any desk to let in connections or just the client to have your Mac take over other remote screens? When you installed any desk 7.0.2 you say the problem remains. Did that install complete correctly and the app launch?

Thank you @bmike, and thank you for your reply. I use AnyDesk for taking over other remote screens, so that is the reason I tried both full and portable installations. Unfortunately, in the case of the version 7.0.2 nothing changed. Again, the full installation got stuck when I pressed “Agree and Install”, and the portable installation, when I launch the app, no window opens and nothing happens.

Ugh. They built their uninstaller into the app, so we might need to go mucking into the package to find the script it runs… hopefully you don’t need their tech support to get uninstall / repair / troubleshoot the install.

So is there anything you suggest I could try?

Yup - open a ticket with support, then proceed to figure if your Mac is broken or the product is broken. See my answer…

Unfortunately, I did not manage to find a solution, because I did not have time to look into it further. I just stopped using it. If there are any suggestions please leave a comment.

Something is really broken for two installers to break. The people who know their product best is AnyDesk support.
If you don’t want to wait for them (if you’re paying for this make them support you), I would do the following in order of importance and ability to figure what’s broken for you.

back up everything you need now. Preferably to a new external drive using Time Machine. You might be getting your final warnings this OS is unstable.
download whichever version of macOS you like fresh from the App Store
install it clean to an external drive (and not to your backup drive)
Do not migrate anything to the new OS on the external
Run the AnyDesk installer + the version you want on the OS you want.

Now you will have flexibility and incontrovertible evidence where your real problem is and can take follow on steps.
If you really don’t care about your setup and apps and data, I would go looking in the package contents of the AnyDesk app to find if their uninstaller is a script you can run  and look at and pick apart what it does.  I would see if the installer writes a log file and logs an install error. But I would only do these if I was being paid to, I don’t have time for installers that don’t log what they do and I always want the fastest path to a stable system which for me is checking my backups, erase install on my main OS if I have time or on an external if I need to test to be sure an erase install will fix my issue.

again thank you for your answer! I won't go this far. I will try to reach AnyDesk support if I can get any help.

Please update us with an answer of your own a week from now (or whenever you get resolution @exch_cmmnt_memb ) . Even if the problem just goes away or you can’t solve it and choose a different product, that will help others know what you did.
